# Set input value after option is set

Tags: angularjs

I have option and input field:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="person in persons">
<select ng-model="person.username" ng-options="item as item.username for item in usernames" ng-change="fillInput()"></select>
<input type="text" ng-model="person.house" readonly="" required="">
<div ng-if="person.username">Full selected user info : {{ person.username | json}}</div>
</div>
```

I want to set input variable every time option is chosen.
Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xr82a1gL/6/). It works fine if I remove `data-ng-repeat="person in persons"` But I need to be able to add few option fields.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: so you want hname withing input field/

Comment: @lin I cant set hname inside input field when option is chosen

Comment: @RakeshBurbure yes, correct

Comment: @YevgeniyBagackiy: please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this below code

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
<br><br>
  <button ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add User</button>
  <div data-ng-repeat="person in persons">
    <select ng-model="person.username" ng-options="item as item.username for item in usernames" ng-change="fillInput()"></select>
    <input type="text" ng-model="person.username.hname" readonly="" required="">
    <div ng-if="person.username">Full selected user info : {{ person.username | json}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The change is in the below line

```
<input type="text" ng-model="person.username.hname" readonly="" required="">
```

You were referencing to invalid value. The variable `person.username` was not pointing anywhere and hence it was not working.

Comment: @YevgeniyBagackiy: you can accept it as an answer if it is working for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
<br><br>
  <button ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add User</button>
  <div data-ng-repeat="person in persons">
    <select ng-model="selectedPerson" ng-options="item as item.username for item in usernames" ng-change="fillInput()"></select>
    <input type="text" ng-model="selectedPerson.hname" readonly="" required="">
    <div ng-if="selectedPerson">Full selected user info : {{ selectedPerson | json}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try this! http://jsfiddle.net/xr82a1gL/18/